# {video:img_url_hd} not working after 3.2 Channel Videos update

Tags: devdemon, channel-videos

The {video:img_url_hd} tag is no longer working after we updated the plugin to the 3.2 version. It displays this gray image:https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GrdZjkNCp8I/sdhqdefault.jpg on the front end, even though the back end shows the correct thumbnail for the video.

I was able to change it to the {video:img_url} version since that is working, but wanted to make sure the DevDemon folks knew about it and check to see if it's just our site that has this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue too. I just updated to 3.2 because the previous version would not even load Youtube videos. I am on ExpressionEngine v2.7.2.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. Please read and follow the rules if you wish to participate on this exchange. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Please submit this as a bug report to the developer rather than posting it here as a question: http://www.devdemon.com/support/form/

Comment: @jchrono-battle I don't know who you are talking to, but this was the first time I have ever posted anything and I have looked at the rules several times and don't know what rule I am not following.

Comment: @DerekHogue I didn't report this as a bug report because they specifically state on their site: "We will not provide direct support for Free Addons unless you have purchased a support license for that Addon." and we have not purchased a support license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please note that the following solution requires modifying a part of the plugins core functionality. Any update to channel_videos is going to remove this fix.**

We resolved it by modifying `line: 235` in `system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_videos/mod.channel_videos.php`. 



**Before:**

`$vars[$prefix.'img_url_hd']    = str_replace('default.jpg', 'hqdefault.jpg', $vid->video_img_url);`

**After:**

`if (strpos($vid->video_img_url, 'sddefault.jpg') !== FALSE) {
    $vars[$prefix.'img_url_hd'] = str_replace('sddefault.jpg', 'hqdefault.jpg', $vid->video_img_url);
} else {
    $vars[$prefix.'img_url_hd'] = str_replace('default.jpg', 'hqdefault.jpg', $vid->video_img_url);
}`

**Whats happening:**

channel_videos searches for `default.jpg` and replaces it with `hqdefault.jpg`.
The problem is that in some instances the string `default.jpg` is actually `sddefault.jpg`.
So when this happens it essentially replaces `default.jpg` of `sddefault.jpg` with `hqdefault.jpg` resulting in the two merging together to become `sdhqdefault.jpg`.

Comment: This doesn't apply with Vimeo.
if I use {video:img_url_hd} I get the _100x75.jpg version.
Also noticed that {video:service_id} doesn't seem to get the correct ID.